# Sybase - Selecting data between 2 dates

Tags: sap-ase

I have another (probably) very easy question to answer regarding sybase ASE 15.5...not my hot topic :-(

I have a temp table which has a date column.

The date is inserted into the temp table using conversion which converts the LIVE data

From

e.g.:

```
2013-01-21 10:05:00.0
2013-01-28 08:03:00.0
```

to

```
21/01/2013
28/01/2013

using (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEFIELD, 103)
```

The problem I am facing is when I try to select data from the LIVE table into the temp table using a date range filter:

```
WHERE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEFIELD, 103) BETWEEN '21/01/13' AND '28/01/13')
```

....when I run this sybase only inserts the 21/01/2013 date and not the 28/01/2013.

.....furthermore if I use 29/01/2013 as end date instead i.e.

```
WHERE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEFIELD, 103) BETWEEN '21/01/13' AND '29/01/13')
```

I get both inserted:

```
21/01/2013
28/01/2013
```

further furthermore - if I run only 21/01/13 i.e.

```
WHERE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEFIELD, 103) BETWEEN '21/01/13' AND '21/01/13')
```

I get nothing returned.

Any ideas?

Perhaps using BETWEEN in sybase is no good.  Just to be clear the fields are converted from DATETIME to VARCHAR (10).

Another problem I have is when I have this first part fix I want to be able to pass a wildcard in e.g.

```
WHERE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEFIELD, 103) BETWEEN '%' AND '%')
```

....but at the moment this one doesn't work either.

Any idea's on either/both of these issues.

Thanks in advance.

Gareth

Answer (score 2):

Well you don't need to convert to varchar. I assume your fields are datetime.

```
convert(date, DATEFIELD, 103)
```

And after you can: 
(TST cenario)

```
create table #temp1 (Datatst datetime)
insert into #temp1 values( '2013-01-21 10:05:00.0')
insert into #temp1 values( '2013-01-28 08:03:00.0')

select Datatst from #temp1
where convert(date,Datatst,103) between '21/Jan/13' AND '28/Jan/13'
```

Datatst

```
2013-01-21 10:05:00.0
2013-01-28 08:03:00.0
```

(my charset is cp850)